# Overriding timeout for database connection in properties file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I was wondering if there is a specific way to override database connection timeout in the properties file in my Java web project? I am using Hibernate, Spring, and MySQL DB. I have tried several different property fields and reduced the timeout time to 1 millsecond, yet the connection is still completed with transactions still being processed properly.

These are the property fields I have used to no avail...

- `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=1`
- `spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout=1`
- `hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1`

Is hibernate overriding this timeout value or am I just setting it improperly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using @Transactional methods and want configure timeout for all of these methods?

Comment: I would ideally like to do for both unless it is impossible to do for methods without @Transactional, for instance, set a database timeout for a method that retrieves a record from the database and another method one that deletes it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using Spring Boot you can try:

```
spring.transaction.defaultTimeout=1
```

This property sets defaultTimeout for transactions to 1 second.

(Looking at the source code of [`TransactionDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html) it seems that it is not possible to use anything more precise than seconds.)

See also: [`TransactionProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionProperties.html)

---

#### `javax.persistence.query.timeout`

This is  a hint for [`Query`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html). It is supposed to work if you use it like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select e from SampleEntity e")
    .setHint(QueryHints.SPEC_HINT_TIMEOUT, 1)
    .getResultList();
```

See also [`QueryHints`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html)

---

### `spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout`

Remember that according to the `JdbcTemplate#setQueryTimeout` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setQueryTimeout-int-):

> Any timeout specified here will be overridden by the remaining transaction timeout when executing within a transaction that has a timeout specified at the transaction level.

---

### `hibernate.c3p0.timeout`

I suspect that this property specifies timeout for getting from the connection pool, not for a query execution

Comment: I tried your first suggestion to no avail. I wonder if not having it in the project accessing the database project is the reason it's not overriding. I have one project with all the web features which access the DAL (Data Access Layer) Project which actually houses the DAOs(Data Access Objects)/Transactional methods. There is a database properties file and application properties file in the web project. Could the fact that there is no properties file in the DAL project be affecting it?

Comment: Most probably yes... But I would suggest you to post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's posiible. It is the best way to help us help you

Comment: Not sure exactly what code to provide... using javax.persistence.EntityManager methods to persist to the database in a DAO class. Those methods are getting called from an "in-between" service layer class, another service layer is calling the methods in the "in-between" service layer class and the service method is being invoked in the controller with a POST method. The first two classes are in the DAL project, the second two classes are in the WEB project. Does that help?

Comment: I am afraid that it won't help. I would like you to post pom/build.gradle for both projects, application.properties, your services, controller and dao. And the file structure. Also did you try `spring.transaction.defaultTimeout` for both of projects?  Are the methods in your services @Transactional? Try to debug `getTransaction` and `commit` methods of `PlatformTransactionManager`. Put a breakpoint in the interface. Are they triggered? If yes then try to execute `getDefaultTimeout` during debugging. What value is returned?

Comment: spring.transaction.default-timeout worked on just the transactional methods.