# How to configure custom database connection timeout in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

In my Spring boot(2.0.7 RELEASE) application I am not able to manually set/override the timeout for the database connections in the application.properites file. I am using JPA, Hibernate, Tomcat connection pool and Postgres.

I've researched thoroughly and found very similar questions :

- [Overriding timeout for database connection in properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599657/overriding-timeout-for-database-connection-in-properties-file)
- [JPA query timeout parameters ignored but @Transaction annotation works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827071/jpa-query-timeout-parameters-ignored-but-transaction-annotation-works)

The reason I ask new question is because neither of the questions above have an accepted answer nor a confirmed working solution. I tried including each proposed solution in my application.properties file with no success.

Also, as mentioned in question 2: if I add parameter 'timeout = someSeconds' in the @Transactional annotation, the connection timeouts as expected but if I try extracting it in the application.properties it fails and timeouts for the default time. The problem here is that I want all connections to timeout in the given time not only the transactions.

Things I've tried in the application.properties (The desired timeout is 4 seconds):

- spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=4000
- spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout=4
- spring.transaction.defaultTimeout=4
- spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout=4

Materials I've read:

- http://www.masterspringboot.com/configuration/web-server/configuring-tomcat-connection-pool-on-spring-boot
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool
- https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/setting#Query_Hints_

Am I missing some property? Does anyone know why the timeout can't be overridden via the application.properties file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per Spring 2.0.7 properties(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) the property key is spring.transaction.default-timeout and not spring.transaction.defaultTimeout.Try it and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, the outcome is the same - the connection does not time out in the specified time. Moreover, I am trying to find a solution that comprises all connections and not only the transactions.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Facing the same issue here...

Comment: Unfortunately no. I haven't found anything new.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least 3 time-outs to configure:

1. Transaction timeouts, which you already did. I declared mine in the transactionManager bean:

```
txManager.setDefaultTimeout(myDefaultValue);
```

2. Query timeouts(which obviously does not need @transactional), which you already did and also explained [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-timeout-jpa-hibernate/)
3. Network timeouts(Read this [excellent article](https://www.cubrid.org/blog/3826470)).

For my case, i am using Oracle, and my bean configuration is as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(springDatasourceDriverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(springDatasourceUrl);
        ds.setUsername(springDatasourceUsername);
        ds.setPassword(springDatasourcePassword);
        ds.setDataSourceProperties(oracleProperties());
        
        return ds;
    }
    
    Properties oracleProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        
        properties.put("oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT", 10000);
        properties.put("oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT", 10000);
        properties.put("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout", 10000);

        return properties;
    }
```

And if you do not want to configure a bean for the DataSource(which is what most people will do), you can configure the network timeout properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=10000
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your datasource, but you can try this:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```