# Spring Boot is ignoring application.properties session timeout value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-session

I'm trying to get Spring Session timeout changed to a longer default value and also to have the cookie be persistent instead of session only. I'm using `spring-session-jdbc` for session storage.

I've put into the `application.properties` file the following:

```
#Distributed Session Storage for use by stateless apps
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

server.servlet.session.timeout=1d
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=1d
server.servlet.session.cookie.same-site=strict
```

Other settings in the `application.properties` file are applied as expected.

It only seems to be the session and cookie settings that aren't being applied.

This is a Spring Boot Jar run via java -jar. The database is MariaDB and sessions are created and managed correctly, but I can't seem to change the cookie or timeout settings.

Help appreciated.
-Michael/NewsRx

Comment: Perhaps try `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie`

Comment: No change when adding this.

Comment: I believe the JDBC session timeout is configured depending on the Connection Pool library. Settings `server.servlet.` are the configurations for the web server. If that's the case check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511297/how-to-configure-custom-database-connection-timeout-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: Not having any issues with the JDBC connection. The issue is with the HTTP Session timeout and cookie settings.

Comment: Your question states: "Spring Session JDBC timeout changed"

Comment: I'll edit the question to clarify that it is 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by Docker not picking up property file changes when rebuilding the container.