# Configuring MySql wait_timeout and interactive_timeout in SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, database-connection

I want to set these two properties:**wait_timeout** and **interactive_timeout** in my SpringBoot project file (application.properties) for database sleep connections problem.
But I'm unable to find help on this from internet not even from spring configurations appendix.

I tried setting these properties from MySql command line,it worked there, but want to set in my spring boot configuration file. (application.properties)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the MySQL configuration file will do the trick. Lot of bugs just blew up on my screen when I altered /etc/*/my.cnf but may be it might work.

- Edit the `my.cnf`

  `sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- Now try to locate the parameters you want
  `[mysqld] wait_timeout = [your value] interactive_timeout = [value needed]`

Then save it and exit

I suggest to restart the MySQL `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

There is no possibility that you can put these at infinite, or I might be wrong.

Comment: oh wait! did you mean in SpringBoot config? Sorry man... Then try this Custom Connection timeout in SpringBoot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511297/how-to-configure-custom-database-connection-timeout-in-spring-boot-application